# Laravel hasOne relationship not loading

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm trying to load a hasOne relationship in laravel with custom fields. This was built on top of an already defined database so i cant modify the database.

I have two tables both on sqlserver 2014 and on different schemas, all PK and FK are integers.

**Tables:**

Table CursoProgramado (schema dbo):
`CursoProgramado(PK) fieldA fieldB`

Table silabos (schema sga):
`id(PK) fieldC fieldD CursoProgramado(FK)`

**Models:**

CursoProgramado

```
class CursoProgramado extends Model {
  protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';
  protected $table = 'CursoProgramado';
  protected $primaryKey = 'CursoProgramado';

   public function silabo()
     {
        return $this->hasOne(Silabo::class, 'CursoProgramado', 'CursoProgramado');
     }
}
```

Silabo

```
class Silabo extends Model {
  protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';
  protected $table = 'sga.silabos';
}
```

**Controller, trying to get the relationship to work**

```
$carga = CursoProgramado::findOrFail($carga);
//this return the model correctly
$carga->silabo;
//this should return the related model but returns NULL

// if i get the query log
DB::connection('sqlsrv')->enableQueryLog();
$carga->silabo;
dd(DB::connection('sqlsrv')->getQueryLog());

// i get this

array:1 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "query" => "select top 1 * from [sga].[silabos] where [sga].[silabos].[CursoProgramado] = ? and [sga].[silabos].[CursoProgramado] is not null"
    "bindings" => array:1 [▼
      0 => 147689
    ]
    "time" => 18.59
  ]
]
//Runnig query
select top 1 * from [sga].[silabos] where [sga].[silabos].[CursoProgramado] = 147689 and [sga].[silabos].[CursoProgramado] is not null;

// it return data
id  CursoProgramado consejeria
1933    147689   La consejerÃ­a y orientaciÃ³n...
```

Not really sure what is causing this

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the belongs to relationship in the Silabo class

```php
class Silabo extends Model {
  protected $connection = 'sqlsrv';
  protected $table = 'sga.silabos';

  public function cursoProgramado()
  {
     return $this->belongsTo(CursoProgramado::class, 'CursoProgramado', 'CursoProgramado')
  }
}
```

cheers

Comment: It is defined, I just didnt include it beacuse i'm only trying to get it from the CursoProgramado model not the other way around. btw it works when I do it that way, the problem is just in this way $carga = CursoProgramado::findOrFail($carga);
$carga->silabo;

Comment: did you set the schema? because it's also omitted in you class definition

Comment: do you mean in CursoProgramado?. No i didn't beacause the connection defaults to that schema and it is working on my other models

Comment: no, I meant in Silabo. I assumed that you use different connections for each schema but I guess you didn't. Use different connections and try. 

FYI using different schemas in the same application is not a good idea IMO, a better approach is to use microservices

Comment: Unfortunately thats how i got the DB and this project required me to work with that DB and the models that are defined or write it all again :/. Just tried with diferrent connections still no luck. For now i'm just going to manually find the related model and go with that i guess. Whats really weird is that similar relations are working so maybe it is the table definition? Never really experienced this problem before